# How to customize linter rules?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to disable the following rule enforcement:

- Name non-constant identifiers using lowerCamelCase.

```
void apply_procedure() {}
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable it in the entire project, add the following in `analysis_options.yaml`:

```
linter:
  rules:
    - non_constant_identifier_names: false
```

Or add the line below above the method signature, as this:

```
// ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
void apply_procedure() {}
```

Or add this to the top of a specific file if you want to disable it in the entire file, and that file only:

```
// ignore_for_file: non_constant_identifier_names
```